# Do office programms make local copy of encrypted files (e.g. 7zip encrypted)?

Tags: encryption, usb, 7-zip

I have a folder with different files .docx, .xlsx etc.
I encrypted the folder on a usb stick with 7zip with password.

When I put the usb in another computer and open a file of this "vault", I browse with 7zip to the file location and press double-click.
The computer opens it with its dedicated app - e.g. Excel or LibreWriter.
Do such programms make local (un-encrypted) copies on the computer? Maybe just temporarely for processing?
And if yes - isn't this a security issue ... e.g. if the app does not get closed correctly?

Greetings
Adam

Answer (score 1):

This is a programming forum, so the question should be placed imho on the infosecurity part of the SO. Regardless that I share an answer.

> Do such programms make local (un-encrypted) copies on the computer?

Short answer - yes.

A little longer answer - the office applications (MS Offce, Libre Office) cannot work with files in an encrypted zip archive. In your case the 7Zip creates a temporary unencrypted file and let the system open the file.

> And if yes - isn't this a security issue

Depends - risk against what? But when it comes to possibility to recover the document content, then yes, it is

Options:

You could use an encrypted volume (truecrypt, veracrypt,..) so you don't create an unencrypted document directly, such as opening from a zip archive.
And you can still encrypt the document content using the office application itself.

It is generally an issue with the mentioned office applications, that they leave temporary content, remember the last open documents,.. So even you can set the content to be encrypted, you still have the file names, sizes, path left behind and it's not easy to ensure denialibility (claim that you never had the document).